# How can I switch images onmouseover/onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to change an static image when you put the mouse over a link. (I created an array for the 3 different images with the three different links and on the array I created the new images.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cambiar = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
  var imgArray = new Array();
    imgArray[0] = document.getElementsByClassName("pricipal");
    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    imgArray[1].src = 'image2.jpg';
    imgArray[2] = new Image();
    imgArray[2].src = 'image3.jpg';
    imgArray[3] = new Image();
    imgArray[3].src = 'image3.jpg';
</script>
<div class="image"><img class="pricipal" src="image1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[1]" onmouseout="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[0]">image2</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[2]" onmouseout="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[0]">image3</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[3]" onmouseout="cambiar.innerHTML=imgArray[0]">image4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `innerHTML`, use the `src` attribute to change the images:
Such that you can have a new array:

```
// Wait for the elements to load first
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var cambiar = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    var imgArray = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];
});
```

Then for your elements:

```
<div class="image"><img class="pricipal" src="image1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.src=imgArray[1]" onmouseout="cambiar.src=imgArray[0]">image2</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.src=imgArray[2]" onmouseout="cambiar.src=imgArray[0]">image3</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="cambiar.src=imgArray[3]" onmouseout="cambiar.src=imgArray[0]">image4</a>
```

Comment: That might work, in the end the error he had was the innerHtml change to src. But it's better done separating the html of the js just with eventListeners and functional programming

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use always functions in JavaScrip.

You could do something like this !

```
<div class="image">
   <img class="pricipal" src="image1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<a href="#" class="imagesToChange">image2</a>
<a href="#" class="imagesToChange">image3</a>
<a href="#" class="imagesToChange">image4</a>
```

Javascript:

```
const imgArray = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];
const allPhotos = document.querySelectorAll('#imagesToChange')

allPhotos.forEach((photo,index)=>{
    photo.addEventListener('mouseover', (ev)=>{
        photo.src = imgArray[index+1]  
        // +1 because the index 0 is the one you want when mouse out
    });


    photo.addEventListener('mouseout'(ev)=>{
        photo.src = imgArray[0]
    });
});
```

Advise you that this code exactly like this **might not work**. I'm not with a code editor right now to try it ! It's you to give you an ide of how to do it better.

I also recomend you to work with event listeners. In the future when you change your code to modules, wont work the htlm onClick and those things, it's more clean to do it with event listeners

Hope you find this helpfull